# Deleted partition - accidentally screwed up other partitions?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am attempting to remove a Debian 8 OS from my computer. I was hoping it'd be as simple as deleting its partition. After I deleted its partition, I ended up with 490GB (/500GB HDD) as "Free Space." Did I make an uh oh??

I had 8 partitions (I think so because I saw sda8). Located at sda8 was my Deb8 OS, & at sda7, my ubuntu OS. Both sized at half of my HDD's space. I open up Disks and selected sda7. I chose to delete the partition. I was asked for pw to make changes. I was left with below...

[image: Disks - Screenshot of my current partitions]

My goal was to remove my SteamOS (Deb8) partition, and adding the space it had taken up to ubuntu.

Comment: Yes , you did make a big mistake by deleting the wrong partition and now you have lost all your data :(

Comment: What was your partition table supposed to look like *before the deletion*? What did you do? Specifically, explain step by step. What do you expect to obtain after the deletion?

Comment: So,  I should never ever shutdown my system? =,(

Comment: NO, you should read the manual before doing stupid things!

Comment: Is there anything I can do? Or is my only option to plug my Ubuntu containing USB in & reinstall?

Comment: You could try to recover partition with `testdisk` : http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15761/recover-data-like-a-forensics-expert-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/. In most cases it doesn't worth the time. It's much easier to reinstall.

Comment: Having a partition called `sda8` is no sign that there were ever 8 partitions on the disk though.

Comment: Rebooting came up with GRUB recovery, so I reinstalled Ubuntu & erased all data off my HDD from USB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up having to **reinstall** both OSes from Live USB. (Ubuntu was very convenient to setup after SteamOS found its home on my SDD.)

**Let the trouble I went through convince others to read manuals!**